# Is it possible to add a lint setting that warns me when there is no newline after a closing curly brace in SublimeLinter-jshint?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

I would like to get warned by the linter when there is no new line after a closing curly brace (with some exceptions). For instance, I want to avoid doing this:

```
if (something()) {
    // ...    
}    
var x = ...;
```

in favor of:

```
if (something()) {
    // ...    
}    

var x = ...;
```

and would like to be prompted by the linter in the former case.

Is there a default setting that I can change? If not and I wanted to create my own, how would I go about doing that?

EDIT: After a bit more digging, it appears that this is a feature of ESLint, under the setting "padding-line-between-statements". So my question can be summed up as: is there an analogous setting in JSHint?

Answer (score -1):

You can check out their website for your indented purpose:
https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/

Or you can also write your own rules:
https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/

Comment: I am not using tslint. I am using jshint.